# Word 2007 - Use only odd numbers for page numbering

Tags: ms-word

How can I set the page numbers for a Word 2007 document to only use odd numbers? So, page 1 would show 1, page 2 would show 3, page 3 would show 5, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the help of MSWord about [formula field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/field-codes-formula-field-HA102017594.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102749146) and this forum post about [field typing](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/formulas-not-working-in-word-2010/d7aea5d4-2821-4b48-b2d3-e7007b3c4319?msgId=66cc633f-a3b1-481e-98f8-30200ca0b3ae) under MSWord, you can type the following:

```
Page { = ({ PAGE }-1)*2+1 } of { = ({NUMPAGES }-1)*2+1 }
```

Whenever you see curly brackets, type Ctrl+F9 to insert them instead of typing them, else it won't work properly. It is mentioned only as a [tip](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-and-format-field-codes-in-word-2010-HA101830917.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102110133) in the Word help also.

You can insert this one as a footer if you want to; inside the page, don't forget to press F9 to update the field values